# Powershell script not outputting ng build progress

Tags: powershell, angular-cli

When I run `ng build` on my Mac through the Terminal, I am able to see the progress of the modules building like so:

[image]

However, when I run `ng build` via Powershell ISE, it doesn't show any output at all, not even the warnings. How can I update my Powershell script so that it shows the build progress percentage and the warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could invoke it through the [call operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html)

```
& ng @( 'build' )
# Explicitly request progress
& ng @( 'build' , '--progress')
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding --progress seemed to do the trick, I should've just tried that sooner. It's odd though that I need to add that flag in ISE but not in Terminal in order to see the output. Would you happen to know the reason for that?